# How to use scanf with 3 integers and '/' between them

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I have started learning C language now a while ago.
Let's say i want to add the birth date, month and year of a random person. 
So the user types the date, month and year in the program. 
I want it to be displayed like this!
Birthday: 20/12/1987 for example but not with the printf!
I want it to be done with the scanf! The problem is how to add the '/' to be displayed in the scanf display in the program.
note: date, month and year are integers

Thank you

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. As an alternative you could ask the user for the day & month & the year separately.

Comment: Try `"%d/%d/%d". You may be surprised.

Comment: The exercise says that i need to add the dd/mm/yy and to be sisplayed like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not that difficult. Just try to do it like you asked:

For a `[integer]/[integer]/[integer]` format, just try this:

```
int day, month, year;
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &day, &month, &year);
```

Comment: It won't automatically display the `/`s, but you have to type an input in that format (for example, you'll have to *input* something like: "20/12/1987"). As far as I know, there isn't a way to create blanks to fill in (such as "  /  /  "). You might be able to do that with multiple lines by asking for them separately like @DeveloperX said.